# Python Selenium, execute ASP.NET AJAX that is normally triggered on an onclick

Tags: python, selenium

I have a web page where I want to do an action defined by an onclick as:

```
onclick = "$find('ReportViewerControl').exportReport('CSV')"
```

I can normally do this without clicking the `<a>` tag that references the `onclick` by typing this command into the console.

Is there anyway to mimic this "typing into the console" that I would normally do to download this csv?

I have no ASP.Net experience at all which is why I am so ignorant about all of the context regarding how that part of the program is being handled. I am just trying to automate the retrieval of this report for parsing in my python program.

The only things that I could think of trying is finding the element that the `<a>` tag is in and clicking on it, which yeilded no results and executing (what I previously assumed was a javascript command) in the window with:

```
browser.execute_script("$find('ReportViewerControl').exportReport('CSV')")
```

which yielded:

```
selenium.common.exceptions.JavascriptException: Message: javascript error: $find is not defined
```

Comment: You can just have Selenium click on the element.  For the javascript, "$" usually means jQuery, so if that site doesn't use that use plain javascript, or inject jQuery first.  Either way the onclick event will be fired.  If the Selenium click isn't working, the onclick event handler may be added after a pageready state.  If so, use a WebDriverWait to generate the click.

Comment: @pcalkins As per what I stated in the question, I already tried that and the file is not downloaded. I have a specific EC / WebDriverWait for the element to be loaded, then clicking yields no result

Comment: ahh, ok... looks like MS is using the $ sign too.  Your problem may have to do with the way you initialize the driver and/or browser.  Headless?

Comment: @pcalkins no, but a new tab is opened when I click the proceeding button which leads to this page, so I think I am "looking" for the element on the right tab.

Comment: If a new tab is opened, you'll need to switch the Selenium driver to it.  browser.switch_to_window(index... you can probably use "1" here)...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you try this and let me know.

```
# Converted the jquery that you will run in the console as "downloadCSV" method
downloadCSV = "window.downloadCSV=function(){$find('ReportViewerControl').exportReport('CSV')}"
# load the method
driver.execute_script(downloadCSV)
# now run the method to execute your manual equivalent action
driver.execute_script("downloadCSV()")
```

Comment: do you mean downloadCSV()? This worked when I used it.

Comment: Yes, Please try with `"downloadCSV()"`. And let me know how it goes through.